# Change div content on selecting option from drop-down select

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jquery, html and css select template, and I added some other code to jquery so for every select option, a specific div is shown. As I'm new in jquery, I cant understand why this part does not function

Html is:

```
    <div class="center">
    <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" 
    placeholder="chose">
      <option value="profile">Profile</option>
      <option value="word">Word</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="ic">IC</div>
    <div id="passport">passport</div>
```

jquery is:

```
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id      = $(this).attr("id"),
      name    = $(this).attr("name");
  var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
      template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
      template += '<div class="custom-options">';
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
      });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);

});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
});

$("#sources").on("change", function() {
  if(this.value == "profile") {
    $("#ic").show();
    $("#passport").hide();
  } else {
    $("#ic").hide();
    $("#passport").show();
  }
});
```

CSS is:

```
body {
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#ic, #passport { display: none; }

/** Custom Select **/
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
  .custom-select-wrapper select {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .custom-select-trigger {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 130px;
      padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 60px;
      background: #5c9cd8;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
      .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
      }
      .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
      }
  .custom-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    .custom-options:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
      width: 7px; height: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -4px;
      border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      background: #fff;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 22px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #b5b5b5;
      line-height: 47px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

the last part of jquery code (.on ("chnge")) is what i added but no results. I expect when Profile is chosen the ic div is shown, else the other div is shown. thank you.

Comment: Make sure your DOM is loaded before your script. If the event is registrated before the DOM is loaded, your event can't be fired

Comment: It looks like your *replacing* the `select` with your own drop-down.  Therefore you're not changing the select value so this code `$("#sources").on("change",` never fires.  You need to hook into the replacement's "select", probably `$(".custom-option").on("click", `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not triggering the `change` event of the HTML select anymore. As you changed and added a custom select.

You can move your `if` statement inside the `click` function on the `custom-option` and show/hide the divs there.

See below ( i also added some code comments ).

In the `if` be sure to change from `$(this).value` to `$(this).data('value')` as you are selecting the `data-value` attribute of the `custom-option`

I won't get into the code itself but it would need some refactoring.

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id      = $(this).attr("id"),
      name    = $(this).attr("name");

  var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
      template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
      template += '<div class="custom-options">';
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        //  $(this).attr("class") will return undefined because this = option and options do not have class
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
      });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);

});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
  
  //change 
   //if($(this).data("value") === "profile") {
    // $("#ic").show();
     //$("#passport").hide();
   //} else {
     //$("#ic").hide();
     //$("#passport").show();
   //}
   
    // in case of switch
    switch($(this).data("value")) {
      case 'profile':
       $("#ic").show();
       $(".custom-content:not(#ic)").hide()
      break;
      case 'example':
       $("#exampleId").show();
       $(".custom-content:not(#exampleId)").hide()
      break;
      default:
        $(".custom-content:not(#passport)").hide()
        $("#passport").show();
     }
    
});

$(".sources").on("change", function() {
 // this is not getting triggered
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*#ic, #passport { display: none; }*/
.custom-content { display: none}

/** Custom Select **/
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
  .custom-select-wrapper select {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .custom-select-trigger {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 130px;
      padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 60px;
      background: #5c9cd8;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
      .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
      }
      .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
      }
  .custom-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    .custom-options:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
      width: 7px; height: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -4px;
      border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      background: #fff;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 22px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #b5b5b5;
      line-height: 47px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="chose">
      <option value="profile">Profile</option>
      <option value="example">Example</option>
      <option value="word">Word</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="ic">IC</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="exampleId">Example</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="passport">passport</div>
```

**EDIT** As per your comment i added a `switch` statement
You just have to set the value which will be compared to different cases. So you set `$(this).data('value')` and then compare it to different values and `hide/show` what you want.

I added an `Example` option to demonstrate how it works.

Also, there is a `default` case to the switch statement which is the one executed when no other case condition has been passed.

Read more here -> [switch statement MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Also i added a common class to the `divs` that were shown/hidden ( `custom-content` )  so it's easier to select what to hide what to show. So you show your div with specific ID and then hide the others.

**EDIT 2**

This is a very specific question. If you don;t give me some general rule that will be applied to these types of cases where you have ' sale ' options, i can just assume that every time the last 2 'words' in the option will be the ' old ' price followed by the ' new ' price.

So, that being said below is the solution.

First, i added a class `sale` to that option that will have this type of content.

Second, check if `this` ( the option ) has that class ( ' sale ' ) then take it's Text and change it before putting it in the new custom select. BE CAREFUL not to change the HTML of the standard HTML select. That's not allowed.

So first i split the option text by spaces ( ' ' ) which returns an array of items. For the sale option it would be ['3','month','30$','20$']. Then, i replace in the Text of the option the item which is the same as the second to last element in the array. So in optiontext i replace 30$ with the same element , 30$ , but wrapped inside `span` tags.

After that, you style that span in CSS with `text-decoration: line-through`

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id      = $(this).attr("id"),
      name    = $(this).attr("name");

  var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
      template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
      template += '<div class="custom-options">';
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        //  $(this).attr("class") will return undefined because this = option and options do not have class
        let optionText = $(this).text()
        if ( $(this).hasClass('sale') ) {
          const arr = optionText.split(' ');
          const newText = optionText.replace(arr[arr.length - 2],`<span class="strike">${arr[arr.length - 2]}</span>`)
          optionText = newText;
        }
       
       
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + optionText + '</span>';
      });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);

});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").html($(this).html());
  
  //change 
   //if($(this).data("value") === "profile") {
    // $("#ic").show();
     //$("#passport").hide();
   //} else {
     //$("#ic").hide();
     //$("#passport").show();
   //}
   
    // in case of switch
    switch($(this).data("value")) {
      case 'profile':
       $("#ic").show();
       $(".custom-content:not(#ic)").hide()
      break;
      case 'example':
       $("#exampleId").show();
       $(".custom-content:not(#exampleId)").hide()
      break;
      default:
        $(".custom-content:not(#passport)").hide()
        $("#passport").show();
     }
    
});

$(".sources").on("change", function() {
 // this is not getting triggered
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*#ic, #passport { display: none; }*/
.custom-content { display: none}

/** Custom Select **/
.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}
  .custom-select-wrapper select {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .custom-select-trigger {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 130px;
      padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 60px;
      background: #5c9cd8;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
      .custom-select-trigger:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 10px; height: 10px;
        top: 50%; right: 25px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transform-origin: 50% 0;
      }
      .custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
        margin-top: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
      }
  .custom-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  .custom-select.opened .custom-options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    .custom-options:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      bottom: 100%; right: 25px;
      width: 7px; height: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -4px;
      border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      background: #fff;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .option-hover:before {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .custom-option {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 0 22px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #b5b5b5;
      line-height: 47px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-option:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .custom-option:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    .custom-option:hover,
    .custom-option.selection {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    .strike {
      text-decoration: line-through;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="chose">
      <option value="profile">Profile</option>
      <option value="example">Example</option>
      <option value="word">Word</option>
      <option class="sale" value="sale">3 month 30$ 25$</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="ic">IC</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="exampleId">Example</div>
<div class="custom-content" id="passport">passport</div>
```

Finally be sure to change in `$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {` from `.find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());` to `.find(".custom-select-trigger").html($(this).html());`  as we are not adding also HTML ( the line-through  )

Comment: Thank you Mihai T, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @MariaFabianHernandes if this solved your question. Please rate/accept my answer. Thank you. Glad i could help. Cheers :D

Comment: one question Miahi, what if I chose to use switch in stead of if-else, in case I gain the number of options, how should I put it?

Comment: @MariaFabianHernandes i edited my answer using a switch statement ( commented out the if statement )

Comment: @MariaFabianHernandes Glad i could help.

Comment: Sorry for too many questions, but after I tried a lot, I couldn't find a solution. In the third option I have <option>3 month 30$ 25$</option>, what I need is to put a line through only in 30$, so user can understand that there is a discount for a 3 month subscription. is it possible to be done in this template? thanks

Comment: @MariaFabianHernandes Well i made a solution. THere might be a better one, but this is what i came up with at ' first ' thought :))

Answer (score 1):

You can just move your onchange code to click function. Bcs basically you don't change select directly but using code inside click function.

```
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());

  if($(this).data("value") == "profile") {
    $("#ic").show();
    $("#passport").hide();
  } else {
    $("#ic").hide();
    $("#passport").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating customized select for better visualization, pls find the codepen link as the result you expected.

```js
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
    id = $(this).attr("id"),
    name = $(this).attr("name");
  var template = '<div class="' + classes + '">';
  template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
  template += '<div class="custom-options">';
  $(this).find("option").each(function() {
    template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
  });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);

});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click', function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select option:selected").val($(this).data("value"));
  console.log($(this).parents(".custom-select-wrapper").find("select").val($(this).data("value")))
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").find(".custom-option").removeClass("selection");
  $(this).addClass("selection");
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  var sel = $(this).parents(".custom-select").find(".custom-select-trigger").text($(this).text());
  console.log($(sel).text())
  if ($(sel).text() == "Profile") {
    $("#ic").show();
    $("#passport").hide();
  } else {
    $("#ic").hide();
    $("#passport").show();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

body {
  background: #ededed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#ic,
#passport {
  display: none;
}


/** Custom Select **/

.custom-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.custom-select-wrapper select {
  display: none;
}

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0 84px 0 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #5c9cd8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-select-trigger:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.custom-select.opened .custom-select-trigger:after {
  margin-top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg) translateY(-50%);
}

.custom-options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.custom-select.opened .custom-options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.custom-options:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 25px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  border-top: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.option-hover:before {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.custom-option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #b5b5b5;
  line-height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.custom-option:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.custom-option:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.custom-option:hover,
.custom-option.selection {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="chose">
      <option value="profile">Profile</option>
      <option value="word">Word</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="ic">IC</div>
  <div id="passport">passport</div>
</div>
```